# Unable to update ubuntu 12.04: GPG error : the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3EF2666A18CEC0F6

Tags: apt, gnupg

```
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3EF2666A18CEC0F6
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch /ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch /ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-4-4/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3EF2666A18CEC0F6`
but it is not working

**Error:**

```
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.zpQPsXehS9 --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3EF2666A18CEC0F6
gpg: requesting key 18CEC0F6 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key 3EF2666A18CEC0F6 not found on keyserver
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

I also tried
`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf`

and after that I tried using `y-ppa-manager`,
but still getting error

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this by going to Update Manager > Settings > Software Sources and unchecking the libre-office-4-4 packages